# How can we get the size of a fileUpload in IE 7-9 without using the ActiveX javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want another way to do this check on the file size instead of using the following code

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var theFile = fso.getFile(<filepath>);
var fileSize = theFile.size;
```